# MS SQL SERVER 2012 - Adventure Works - Triggers INSTEAD OF

Tags: sql-server, triggers

My objective is to create an `INSTEAD OF` `trigger` on a table that fires **only** if a Boolean predicate is satisfied. The MSDN SQL TRIGGER webpage does not provide and example and thus suggests, to me, that it is not possible.

An alternative:

1. Use an `AFTER` `trigger`.
2. `SELECT` for certain values.
3. `IF` x `ROLLBACK`

This seems wasteful. Does this reduce the time an `UPDATE LOCK` is required?

**EDIT: Extension of question in response to Dan Guzman's comment:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER HumanResources.trg_deptUpdate 
ON HumanResources.Department
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS 
    PRINT N'Department details are to be amended only be authorized staff.';
GO

--2 Test trigger.
UPDATE HumanResources.Department
SET Name = 'Funny Team'
WHERE Name = 'Sales';
```

**EDIT2: Amendments made to code as advised by Ben in *ANSWER1*:**

```
--!1 Simple TRIGGER that prevents UPDATES of the form X the the Department table.
--!X=[name]='Funny Team'
CREATE TRIGGER HumanResources.trg_deptUpdate
ON HumanResources.Department
WITH ENCRYPTION
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
    IF (SELECT COUNT(Name)
    FROM HumanResources.Department
    WHERE Name = 'Funny Team') > 0
        ROLLBACK;
        RAISERROR('This is message HRu1: You cannot insert silly values'
                ,6      -- Severity 6; business rule level message.
                ,1);    -- State 1; not sure of the implication (State !=0) = operation failure?
GO
```

Comment: An `INSTEAD OF` trigger will fire, but you can short-circuit execution according to your predicate with a `IF` statement.  Post an example of what you want to accomplish if you need help with the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to enforce security, use the security options. Only give authorised staff UPDATE permission on the table.

Second, to enforce non-security business rules, you just use an AFTER trigger and `raiserror` if business rules are violated. Look at the `IF .... BEGIN ... END` control flow construct.

Although you could use an INSTEAD trigger, that's not really what they are for. INSTEAD triggers are for making views updatable.

Comment: Ben, please state whether EDIT2 in my QUESTION is a code revision that reflects your suggestions. Thanks Ben.

Comment: No, you need to use BEGIN and END for the trigger itself and also for the IF block.